# Repeated CSS background

Tags: css

My website appears like (see attached screenshot) on higher resolutions. You can see a yellow badge and blue arrow are repeated in 2k pc resolution.

How can i disable this? not repeated? Please see my style.css below.

[image: Thanks. [Link to image.][1]]

```
@charset "utf-8"; body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; background: url(images/main_bg.gif); font: normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } html { padding:0; margin:0;}

a { text-decoration:none;} a:hover { text-decoration:underline;} /* main */ .main { padding:0; margin:0 auto;}

/********** header **********/
.blok_header {  margin:0;   padding:0;  background: url(images/header_bg.gif) top center repeat-x;  border-bottom-width: 1px;   border-bottom-style: solid;     border-bottom-color: #dddddd; }
.header { width:960px; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}
.header h2 { font:normal 36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#3c3c3c; padding:20px 0 20px 15px; margin:0; width:540px; float:left;}
.header p { font: italic 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0e0e0e; padding:25px 0 0 0; margin:0; width:400px; float:right; line-height:1.5em;}
.header a { color:#0096ce; text-decoration:none;}

/* logo */
.logo { padding:0; margin:0 auto; width:267px;}
.rss { width:200px; float:left; font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ecece3; padding:10px 10px 5px 0; margin:0;} 
.rss a { margin:0; padding:0; float:right; display:block; width:16px; height:16px; padding:0 3px;}
.text {     width:320px;    text-align:right;   float:right;    margin:0;   padding:10px 0 0 20px;  font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     color:#ffffff; }
```

Comment: use : background-repeat:no-repeat;

Answer (score 2):

In your header you set the repeat to `repeat-x`. Change that line to:

```
.blok_header {  margin:0;   padding:0;  background: url(images/header_bg.gif) top center no-repeat;   border-bottom-width: 1px;   border-bottom-style: solid;     border-bottom-color: #dddddd; }
```

Comment: i have changed no-repeat, but now it's showing like this: http://tinypic.com/r/vzd6jc/8

Comment: @user3779881 The image you provided isn't sufficient to help you out. That said, why not change the background image to two absolutely position div elements that are set to be on top using z-index? That might work just as well. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting background-repeat to no-repeat, like so:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```